# Remove <timestamp> tag from ws-security headers created by WSO2 policy

Tags: soap, wso2, ws-security

i'd like to remove "**Timestamp**" tag from SOAP headers and send Security headers like this:

```
  <soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:UsernameToken>
           <wsse:Username>Username</wsse:Username>
           <wsse:Password>Password</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
```

I use WSO2 esb. Proxy service with policy.

Comment: Try to share the policy as well (without passwords). On the other hand - the timestamp is important part of the UsernameToken parameter. The timestamp is present to mitigate the replay attack possibility

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want this removed?

Comment: There are several rules that are used to invoke internal services. At the moment, I can not change rules for SOAP headers auth for all sysrtems.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<sp:IncludeTimeStamp>` tag inside Policy xml and open and save the proxy service that uses this policy. Then only the proxy will load the changed policy xml and the change will get reflected in the proxy.